# How to design interface for backups that users can restore to

Tags: interface, user-centered-design, customer-experience, ease-of-use

I am currently working on a system for our application where users can restore to backups done previously. The current setup is that the system backups everyday when automatic backups are on. Now our users can also restore to a backup done previously at a given time such a differential backups. How to create an easy to use UI for the Application so that they can restore to these previous backups done throughout the day if needed?

My initial approach was a particular day and underneath the date, a slider that can be used to restore to? Keeping in mind that our users are 40+ years**+** old.

Comment: Do you have some mocks with the current context? Showing us examples of your efforts with some details will get some more thorough answers and add value to future forum users

Comment: As @MikeM already told you, please, add what you already tried then we can talk about. Unfortunately, the idea of this community is not to do your job. Then please show us more details and wireframes or templates and will love to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the filters for data can be help here
(although not necessarily? Because if we lose important data, we usually try to recover it as soon as possible (the same day or slightly earlier)

At the level when there is nothing declared - a list will be useful - a set of all backups with parameters (execution time, backup life cycle)after selecting the appropriate item in the list (choosing the target backup from the list - confirmation message - "Are you sure to perform the backup"

I'm guessing the application is already designed(aesthetic rules, design system etc.) , so the implementation of new functionalities should be based on existing patterns.